# Maven assembly, jar-with-dependencies and excluded project class(es)

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, program-entry-point

I have a Maven project with one class with main method and I'd like to create one big executable jar with Maven. Here's the configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.kawaiisoft.Miku</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The class is specified in `mainClass` element. Next I do:

```
mvn assembly:single
```

and Maven creates `target/miku-cli-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. Great so far. Except the main class is not included in the jar while all dependencies are there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the main class part of this maven module or is an external class?

Comment: I would recomment the maven-shade-plugin

Comment: The configuration is correct and exactly the same thing works perfectly well on my machine.

Comment: Does it work if you package the app first, e.g. `mvn clean package assembly:single`?

Comment: Main class is part of Maven module. I'm not going to struggle with another Maven crap plugin. Yes I do clean first. It started working after I added <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> to manifest which added jar file names to Class-Path in manifest (in addition to packing them in one jar) which is something I don't want but it works so whatever, I don't care. Useless Maven piece of crap...

Comment: Maybe `mvn assembly:assembly` works better?

Comment: Works for me when doing `mvn clean package assembly:single` as suggested by @user944849